# as3 initialize class constructor from another class

Tags: actionscript-3, class, package

I am very FRESHLY new to packages so forgive my simple question. How do I initialize the docTwo class and constructor function? I figured out how to call a static function from the main class but not to init another class.  Thanks

**myDocClass.as**

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import docTwo;



public class myDocClass extends MovieClip 
{

    var Hello:String = "Hi there";

    public function myDocClass () 
        {
        trace("And all the people said...  " + Hello);
        docTwo.docTwo(); /// Does NOT WORK. How do I call this or init class? 
        thisWorks();
                    // Below call Works
        docTwo.docTwoFunction();
        }

        public function thisWorks()
        {
            trace("Cool Beans! This one worked");
        }

}/// end of Class


}
```

**docTwo.as**

```
package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class docTwo{

    public function docTwo() 
    {
        trace("Trying to get this to work!");
        docTwoFunction(); // How do I call this from here?
    }

    static public function docTwoFunction()
    {
        trace("I am inside docTwo. Woo hoo!");
    }

}

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your `myDocClass` like this:

```
public class myDocClass extends MovieClip 
{

    var Hello:String = "Hi there";
    var myDocTwo:docTwo ;

     public function myDocClass () 
        {
           trace("And all the people said...  " + Hello);
           myDocTwo = new docTwo();

    ...
    ...
```

Note , they're both placed in the same package.

Comment: That was it. Awesome. Thanks so much. It's all a bit mind bending sometimes but I am sure with time I will get it.

Comment: so myDocTwo = new docTwo(); is what calls it? and you need to declare the class at the top? Is that what you did?

Comment: @PapaDeBeau i defined `myDocTwo` as variable with `docTwo `  , and instantiated it only in `myDocClass ` constructor

Comment: I removed the import docTwo and it still worked. Why is that?

Comment: @PapaDeBeau yes , `new docTwo()` is what calls the class' constructor

Comment: @PapaDeBeau because they're both are part of same package , so no need to import them

Comment: interesting. What if i placed it in a com folder? How would I import it then?

Comment: @PapaDeBeau `import com.*;` and in the class in this package you need write `package com` and not just `package`

Comment: ok I think I am getting it. So all .as packages in the com folder would be this way too. And if I wanted to import from another folder it would be package myFolder etc... ? wild. I wonder about subfolders. :)

Comment: @PapaDeBeau it is not difficult  , but i just don't want to confuse you because of my english. look at Adobe's Official , and you'll get it in 5 minutes: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/packages.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31429/discussion-between-papa-de-beau-and-cherniv)